# How to filter records in a single section of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have my base record set filtered with a parameter. However, this leaves me with 6 records and I need to filter down to one particular record in each of my sections. If none of the records meet my criteria i cannot suppress the section, it will need to just stay there and blank.

Essentially, I need a method to filter down records that hit one of my sections but not affect the report as a whole.

A few notes:

- I cannot use a subreport for this. I need to duplicate this effort over a couple of sections and if I add any more sub reports it just crashes crystal reports (I have a lot of data & a ticket with SAP)
- Using a suppression formula hasn't worked yet because I need the section to exist, if it has a null value
- Applying no filter doesn't help me because it will duplicate my section 6 times

Answer (score 1):

2 options.

a)

1. Right Click on white space and choose Insert Group
2. Choose your field and select specified order or use another record that can filter your data
3. On the Specified Order Tab click New
4. Select equal to on the combo box and specified what record you need to be shown

or

b)

1. Right click on the record
2. Next to the suppress check box, click on x-2
3. Here you can create a formula to suppress the records that you don't need.